# When I call Count method in Entity Framework, does it process all the columns or just one or what?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, optimization

Im looking for otimization.

When I call Count method in Entity Framework, does it process all the columns or only one or what?

If you also have any official site talking about this, I would appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some tests a while ago and found out that EF does a count on the server, it sends a query with a SELECT COUNT so it does not load all records for sure.

about the columns, if you are referring to the difference between `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(Id)` or `COUNT(1)` I have read somewhere a while ago that for SQL Server there is no difference, the `COUNT(*)` is optimized as `COUNT(1)` anyway.

you could read many articles online or question here on SO... not excatly 100% what you asked but similar topics on performances of EF and ORM...

[How to COUNT rows within EntityFramework without loading contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890381/how-to-count-rows-within-entityframework-without-loading-contents)

http://ayende.com/blog/4387/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-nhibernate-linq-to-sql-entity-framework-scenario-analysis

[How to optimize Entity Framework Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233245/how-to-optimize-entity-framework-queries)

Comment: You beat me to it. I was also going to add the link to a post about the performance of Count in general http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/02/c.net-little-wonders-empty-defaultifempty-and-count.aspx

Comment: SQL Profiler enabled, then make a sample program in .NET and EF and capture all calls to the database. You are using MS SQL Server right?

Comment: actually Im using mysql, but I dont think there will be a difference. Well, you said the query was "SELECT COUNT", but was that "SELECT COUNT (*) or SELECT COUNT (column_name)". If im not wrong, the count with column_name is faster and dont bring all the data.

Comment: it was surely not a *, was COUNT(1) and you can test this against SQL Server. Is there a connector EF -> MySQL already?!

Comment: good! yes there is already an official connector: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
hey, can you check if the query using a WHERE name.Contains("Jack") still COUNT(1)? Because this way, the result may be different of a GetAll count. Thank you.

Comment: I will try this SQL Profiller to do more tests ^^